# How is user input submitted in bootstrap 3 form?

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, initializr

I'm using bootstrap 3, which includes jquery 1.11.2.min.js. I'm updating a search webpage with two textfields: keyword and city,state,zip. I have a script for the search results that needs to pull the user input that's typed into these two search textfields for finding the desired search results.

Visual explanation:
My search bar with placeholders and search button:
[image]

My search bar with my user input (searching for an engineering job in Boston):
[image]
In the HTML, there is no unique value (value="Engineer" or value="Boston") created for my engineering job in Boston search:
[image]

Without value="Engineer" and value="Boston" I cannot tell my script to display search results of engineering jobs in Boston. Where do I find/create this to pull into my search script?

Is this located in the bootstrap.js file anywhere? I'm having trouble figuring out where/how this form is pulling the user input value (without having to use value="" for each input).

Your help is much appreciated - my form is below.

```
<div id="somebanner" class="somebanner-bgsearch-red hero1 hidden-xs">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="top-section">
        <div class="container">
          <form class="form-inline no-margin center-block" action="http://www.somesite.com/unknown" method="POST" role="form">
            <div class="row">
              <center>
              <fieldset>

                <!-- Search input-->
                <div class="form-group center-block">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input id="keyword" name="keyword" type="search" placeholder="Keyword" class="form-control input-lg">

                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Search input-->
                <div class="form-group center-block">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input id="location" name="location" type="search" placeholder="City, State, or Zip Code" class="form-control input-lg">

                  </div>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="unknown" value="unknown">

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group center-block">
                  <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <button type="submit" id="btn-search" name="btn-search" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-tusaj">Search</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </center>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the link to the bootstrap.js code: http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js

Herer's the link to the jquery code:
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js

[image]

Comment: I think you're under the impression Bootstrap can do things it isn't designed to do.

Comment: i second james. the html code that you have posted does not related to the functionality that you have described

Comment: Can you include the JavaScript code for the Boostrap controller or view?

Comment: Nothing shown would populate the values except for possibly browser `autocomplete` which can be disabled using proper attribute. Your problem is not clear

Comment: Do you need to get the value of the 2 search fields? Please clarify your problem.

Comment: I added the links to the js files.

My problem is that I can't link my script to a unique user input value. If I use value="", it overrides my placeholders. However, I see when testing the form (me typing into these textfields), the textfields nicely replace these placeholders with my text, but I can't find the actual values for my typing to use in my script - I was thinking the mechanism for this was in bootstrap.js or jquery. If I'm wrong, where/how do I get this value?

Comment: The functionality of the `placeholder` attribute is built into the browser.   Otherwise, cannot make any sense about what you're asking.

Comment: Let me see if I can rephrase my question.

Comment: @AbraarArique That's exactly my problem, yes. I need to get the value of the 2 search fields. 

I updated my question with added visuals for better understanding as well.

Comment: @JBear So all you need to do is when clicked on "Search", the input values of the search fields should get attached to your HTML like `<input type="text" value="Engineer">`. Right?

Comment: @AbraarArique That's correct, but I am not seeing this happening.

Comment: @JBear Ok, I understand your problem. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: @AbraarArique thank you for your answer - I have some additional questions to your answer below (in a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use Bootstrap for modifying HTML, but Bootstrap is a CSS framework used for responsive design. It's incapable of doing such HTML modification. You need to use **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn-search").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $("#keyword").val();
    var y = $("#location").val();
    $("#keyword").attr("value", x);
    $("#location").attr("value", y);
  });
});
```

That should do the work. If you have further questions, let me know in the comments.

Comment: two additional questions from this:
1. Do I need to create specific input IDs or names to reference in jquery or or the placeholder works?
2. In mobile, I hide this search bar and show a button for a search dropdown in its place. Since these are two different forms performing the exact same function, how would I differentiate between the two forms in the jquery (I'm thinking of 1 jquery script for each form, but need to differentiate between the two forms' keyword and city,state,zip text fields)?

Comment: Ans 1: In the code you provided on your question already has an `id="keyword"` and `id="location"` on the specific  `<input>` tags. The jQuery selector needs these 2 ids to find the `<input>` tags. So you have to provide 2 ids to the respective `<input>` tags.

Comment: As for question 2: So the situation is you're showing a different form on mobile devices; but that form needs to do the same (i.e. set the `value ` attribute of `<input>`). In a situation like this what you can do is: add the mobile form's "Search" tag's `id` to the 2nd line of my answer: `$("#btn-search, #btn-mobile-search").click(...)`. That way, the code will get called for normal search as well as on the mobile search.

Comment: I have an additional question to add to this:
Say A user is based in Boston. How could I add to this jQuery code to automatically insert value="Boston" for #location?

OR

Say a user searches for Manager. On the search results page, how would I prepopulate value="Manager" for #keyword?

Comment: @JBear You can insert the value "Boston" like `$("#location").val("Boston");`. The same goes for `#keyword`: `$("#keyword").val("Manager");`.

Comment: So it's like an if/else statement like this:

Comment: @JBear If you specify a value with the `val()` function it'll set the appropriate value. Otherwise it'll return the current value. It's use to both get and set values. Reference: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: I just tested this code and it doesn't seem to work. The jQuery file is linked to this testpage.html. Do you know why? I added the screenshot to my question - you'll see my "Nurse" value isn't replacing the placeholder.

Comment: @JBear Just use `$("#keyword").val("Nurse");`, no need for `var x` or `attr`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It won't replace the placeholder.

Comment: @JBear I think the problem is a bit complex. Can you post a new question  with all your current code and send me the question link here?

Comment: @AbrarArique Sure thing - Here's the new question and link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566051/jquery-code-wont-connect-to-search-form